# CosmosDB change feed, leases and azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb, serverless

I've recently started working with Azure CosmosDB and functions. While reading documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed-processor I found something that is quite hard to understand for me. Is it actually possible to share a change feed between many functions so they will be triggered by one and same db operation? What is the lease collection and what problem does it solve. What is the purpose of lease? I'd like to have a basic explaination of these terms. In the link i provided it is said that it is possible to share a lease between two functions but then it is said that a lease object has an owner property.

Comment: https://medium.com/@gary.strange/cosmosdb-change-feed-processing-c002448a6ca

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can have multiple functions being triggered from the same change. However this requires you to have separate leases for them. They can live in the same lease collection but they need a different prefix. There is a setting for that. In Azure functions it's the `leaseCollectionPrefix` attribute property.

Leases are really just documents like any other in Cosmos DB that will be used to keep track of the consumers for this change feed processor and save some checkpoints so they know where to continue if your app restarts.

Comment: Oh I see, but now I got another question though. Container is splitted into physical partitions that contain logical partitions. Is there a seperate change feed for each logical parition? If so does it mean that there are two leases for one partition if two azure functions share the same feed?

Comment: @Alienown No, the change feed is one per container. Each physical partition will be processed in a separate thread within that single change feed instance. If more change feeds for this collection with the same lease are created then some of those physical partition leases/threads will be dropped and the new app will pick them up. They's how the change feed scales out.

Comment: Allright, few more questions (I hope so). Why do I need two functions to have different leases and moreover - if they are bound to leases processed by different change feed processors (different prefixes), how is it possible for them to react on db change that was registered on different lease than the function is currently bound to ("Yes you can have multiple functions being triggered from the same change")?

Comment: You might wanna process the changes differently or you might be interested on specific documents, since the change feed doesn't have any sort of filtering before the file is received.

Comment: So given two documents on the same partition, they will land only in function that has the lease prefix targeting this partition, right? The other function might not get that change because of different prefix. Is that how it works?

Comment: The lease prefix is not relate to the processing. It's just something you define and it can be any string. The document will always be processed by every function that's responsible for this partition key range. The prefix will just allow you to have multiple change feed processors to target the same collection and processes everything independently.

Comment: Understood. The picture at the bottom of linked documentation page got me wrong. I thought that functions are directly bound to specific lease and thus a partition.

Comment: @NickChapsas I have one question here... i have two small containers for those 2 i have built two different host of change feed processor, can i share a single lease collection for those, should not create any problem in future right ?